# GridLayout in QML how to constraint Rectangle in a cell

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am using the below code hoping to set my `Rectangle` in the top middle of the `Item`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 5
        rows: 7

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 2

            color: "#ffffff"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead the `Rectangle` is filling the whole item.

Comment: How do you expect something else, when you have the `GridLayout` filling the `Item` and in the `Rectangle` `Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.fillWidth: true`, therefore instructing the `Rectangle` to fill as much space while respecting the constraints (i.e. not surpassing its `maximumWidth/Height` and not shrinking `Item`s in the neighboring fields)

Answer (score 0):

I see so everything is relative in `GridLayout` and if things don't properly take a specified span then it's a "manure" show.
The following works for me.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            id: top_center
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.row: 0
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 1

            color: "#ffffff"
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.columnSpan: 1

            color: "lightblue"
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.row: 1
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.rowSpan: 3
            Layout.columnSpan: 6

            color: "white"
        }
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.row: 4
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: 6

            color: "lightblue"
        }
    }
}
```